# Using Google Sign In Frameworks in a Cocoapod Subspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-signin

I have a Cocoapod I'm building that allows Pod users to optionally use Google Sign In-- I'm trying to include Google Sign In as a Subspec in the Cococapod subspec. Direct use of this, e.g., in the subspec, something like:

```
  s.subspec 'Google' do |google|
    google.dependency 'GoogleSignIn'
  end
```

doesn't appear to work because it causes transitive static framework inclusion errors.

I'm having somewhat better luck by directly including the relevant Google frameworks. I.e., by downloading the frameworks here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/, putting these in my Cocoapod project, and then using:

```
  s.subspec 'Google' do |google|
    google.xcconfig = { 
        'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -DSYNCSERVER_GOOGLE_SIGNIN',
        'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -ObjC'
    }

    google.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/SDKs/google_signin_sdk_4_1_2'
    }

    google.frameworks = ['GoogleSignIn', 'GoogleSignInDependencies']

    google.resource_bundles = {
      'GoogleSignIn' => ['$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/SDKs/google_signin_sdk_4_1_2/*.bundle']
    }
  end
```

The above will build in my project when I use it locally. That is, when I do the following in my Podfile:

```
pod 'SyncServer/Google', :path => '..'
```

However, if I try to validate the podspec in preparation for committing it to my Git repo:

```
pod lib lint
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> - ERROR | [iOS] [SyncServer/Google] file patterns: The `resource_bundles` pattern for `GoogleSignIn` did not match any file.
> - ERROR | [iOS] [SyncServer/Google] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
> ```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

---

Further comment 1)
I suspect my issue has to do with my usage of $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT). the "SDKs" directory is in the root of my project. It seems that `$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)` resolves to the root when using the pod with a local path reference, but not when trying to lint the project.

Answer (score 0):

To directly depend on a static vendored_framework like `GoogleSignIn`, use the [static_framework podspec attribute](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#static_framework).

Comment: I am using this in a subspec, and I get an Xcode error: `unsealed contents present in the bundle root`.

Comment: If I use `GoogleSignIn` as a direct dependency and don't use a subspec I get the same Xcode error.

Comment: After not being able to get the GoogleSignIn framework to work in the way I needed as a static framework, I converted it to a dynamic framework. See https://github.com/crspybits/GoogleySignIn

Comment: Well, that last one didn't quite work. Problems with accessing GoogleSignIn.bundle. I'm going to delete that repo above-- try this one: https://github.com/crspybits/GoogleSignIn This one can be installed as a Cocoapod so might make it easier to use.